# Exclude Draft Post in related Post Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am currently using a custom code for related post filtered by category that displays 4 related posts.
My code works fine except it also displays the draft posts. which ideally it should and is a bit frustrating. Here is my code for the related post.

```html
<div class="relatedposts">
<?php
// get current post categories and tags
$categories = get_the_category($post->ID);
$tags = get_the_tags($post->ID);
if ($categories || $tags) {
  $category_ids = array();
  if($categories)
  foreach($categories as $individual_category) $category_ids[] = $individual_category->term_id;
  $tag_ids = array();
  if($tags)
  foreach($tags as $individual_tag) $tag_ids[] = $individual_tag->term_id;
  
  $args=array(
    'tax_query' => array(
      'relation' => 'OR',
      array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'field' => 'id',
        'terms' => $category_ids
      ),
      array(
        'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
        'field' => 'id',
        'terms' => $tag_ids
      )
    ),
    'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
    'posts_per_page'=> 4, // Number of related posts that will be shown.
  );
  // query posts
  $my_query = new WP_Query( $args );
  if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
    ?>
    <div class="related-post-title">
    <?php
    echo "<h2>Related Health Hub Articles</h2>";
    ?>
    </div>
    <?php
    while( $my_query->have_posts() ) { $my_query->the_post();
      // display each post
      ?>
      <div class="related-post-thumb col-sm-3">
        <a href='<?php the_permalink(); ?>' rel='canonical' class="related-wrapper">
            <div class="related-thumb"><?php the_post_thumbnail(array(150,100)); ?></div>
            <h4 class="related-title"><?php the_title();?></h4>
        </a>
      </div>
      <?php
    }
  }
}
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

I have reviewed your code. you have missed the post_status column. Anything with the status "publish" is what you want.

Please add `'post_status' => 'publish'` in $args array.

You can see built-in WordPress functions.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Integrating_WordPress_with_Your_Website

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<div class="relatedposts">
<?php
// get current post categories and tags
$categories = get_the_category($post->ID);
$tags = get_the_tags($post->ID);
if ($categories || $tags) {
  $category_ids = array();
  if($categories)
  foreach($categories as $individual_category) $category_ids[] = $individual_category->term_id;
  $tag_ids = array();
  if($tags)
  foreach($tags as $individual_tag) $tag_ids[] = $individual_tag->term_id;

  $args=array(
    'tax_query' => array(
      'relation' => 'OR',
      array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'field' => 'id',
        'terms' => $category_ids
      ),
      array(
        'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
        'field' => 'id',
        'terms' => $tag_ids
      )
    ),
    'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
    'posts_per_page'=> 4, // Number of related posts that will be shown.
    'post_status'      => 'publish'
  );
  // query posts
  $my_query = new WP_Query( $args );
  if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
    ?>
    <div class="related-post-title">
    <?php
    echo "<h2>Related Health Hub Articles</h2>";
    ?>
    </div>
    <?php
    while( $my_query->have_posts() ) { $my_query->the_post();
      // display each post
      ?>
      <div class="related-post-thumb col-sm-3">
        <a href='<?php the_permalink(); ?>' rel='canonical' class="related-wrapper">
            <div class="related-thumb"><?php the_post_thumbnail(array(150,100)); ?></div>
            <h4 class="related-title"><?php the_title();?></h4>
        </a>
      </div>
      <?php
    }
  }
}
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$search_query=get_search_query();

function __extra_where($sql){
  global $wpdb;
  return ' AND '.$wpdb->prefix.'posts.post_status="publish" AND ( 1=1 '.$sql.' ) ';
}
add_filter( 'posts_where', '__extra_where', 10, 2 );

$query = new WP_Query(array(
  'post_status' => array( 'publish' ),
  'post_type' => ['post'/*your post_type here */],
  's'=>$search_query,
  'order' => 'ASC'
));
remove_filter( 'posts_where', '__extra_where', 10 );
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.